# Does the series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to check if the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log n\log (n+1)}$$ converges.

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log n\log (n+1)}$.

I found that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rightarrow 1$ so we cannot use this criterion, right?

What could we do?

Comment: It converges. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%7B1%2F%7Bn*log%7Bn%7D*log%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D). It seems wolfram alpha uses a "comparison test" for that

Comment: About the quotient (and root) test(s): is a rather weak criterion because is actually a comparison with a geometric series. When the general term is $O(1/n^{O(1)})$ the limit of the quotient (if exists) is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that
\begin{equation}
\log n < \log (n+1)
\end{equation}
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then
\begin{equation}
0\le \frac{1}{n\log n \log(n+1)} < \frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}
\end{equation}
and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ converges. By comparison test, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log n \log(n+1)}$ converges.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). We have that
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n\log n\log(n+1)}\le\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n\log^2 n}\le\int_2^\infty\frac1{x\log^2 x}\mathrm dx=\biggl[-\frac1{\log x}\biggr]_2^\infty=\frac1{\log 2}.
$$
Hence, the series converges.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

As
$$\frac{\frac{1}{n\log n\log(n+1)}}{\frac{1}{n\log n\log n}}\to 1$$
and
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$$
is convergent by the integral criterion, your series is convergent.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm using the quotient form of the criterion. See http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx.